# Scala Currying: Overriding function with an empty argument by a partial function

Tags: scala, overriding, abstract, currying, partialfunction

I'm trying to implement/override a function with an empty input argument by using partial function. It is best explained by this non-working minimal example:

```
trait T
trait TFactory {
  def build(): T
}

class A(someParameter: Int) extends T

object A extends TFactory {
  def build(someParameter: Int)(): T = new A(someParameter)
}
```

The compiler complains: `object creation impossible, since method build in trait TFactory of type ()T is not defined`, which makes sense, since the type of build is `(Int)()T`. My next idea was to make the type of `build` explicitly to a function taking an empty argument and returning a `T`, i.e.:

```
trait T 
trait TFactory {
  def build: () => T    // what about empty parenthesis after build?
}

class A(someParameter: Int) extends T 

object A extends TFactory {
  def build(someParameter: Int): (() => T) = (() => new A(someParameter))
}
```

Now it is obvious that the type of `build` is `() => T`. To my surprise the compiler now complains about `object creation impossible, since method build in trait TFactory of type => () => T is not defined` (note the type suddenly starts with a `=>`). Desperately adding empty parenthesis at the end of the function definition(s) does not help either.

How can I convince my compiler that these types actually are the same?

**Clarification:**

My primary goal is to achieve a parameter-free initialization of `T` without the need of a factory for factories. Example:

```
val t = A(33).build()      // if this is possible, I though it might be possible to have:
val t = A.build(33)()
```

**Conclusion:**

I think it is just not possible, because the abstract function simply determines how many argument blocks the `build` function must take. In other words: You cannot by implemented an abstract function by a function, whose *partial application* happens to have the same signature as the function you are trying to implement.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  TFactory promises to provide a method "build" that takes no parameters and returns either a T (in the first example) or a function returning T (in the second).  But no such method is defined in object A.

Comment: The intended behavior of `build` is to take nothing as input and return a new instance of `T`. The intention behind the implementation in `object A` is simply to wrap all necessary parameters of `A` allowing a "parameter-free" initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not exactly sure what you want to achieve. Let's say your `TFactory` was given as in your first example:

```
trait T

trait TFactory {
  def build(): T
}
```

Then the `build` method obviously cannot take any parameter. If you want to *configure your factory*, you can have a factory-factory:

```
class A(x: Int) extends T

object A {
  def apply(x: Int): TFactory = new TFactory {
    def build() = new A(x)
  }
}

val factory = A(33)
val t = factory.build()
```

---

If you define `TFactory` simply to be a function from `()` to `T`, you can use currying

```
type TFactory = () => T

object A {
  def apply(x: Int)(): T = new A(x)
}

val factory: TFactory = A(33) _
val t = factory()
```

Comment: And shouldn't it be possible to achieve exactly the same by currying the `build` function? After all, my primary goal indeed was to avoid a FactoryFactory. I was hoping to achieve this parameter-free initialization simply by returning a function of the type `() => T`, which seems to be possible since the types in the examples are "almost right".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I think my main problem with this solution is that I cannot enforce that everyone who implements `T` should also provide a parameter-free way to instantiate a `T`. My original goal was to have a `val factory: TFactory` within `T`, which would have enforced this link (sorry that I failed to make that clear enough).

Comment: For sake of completeness: I asked a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20542997/1804173) which deals with the big picture behind this question; Or in other words: This question here was simply a completely misguided attempt to come up with an alternative solution to that other question. I've added a corresponding conclusion above and accept this answer, unless anybody will prove that my conclusion is wrong.